# List that resembles a dict to dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that already quite resembles a dictionary:

```
l=["'S':'NP''VP'", "'NP':'DET''N'", "'VP':'V'", "'DET':'a'", "'DET':'an'", "'N':'elephant'", "'N':'elephants'", "'V':'talk'", "'V':'smile'"]
```

I want to create a dictionary keeping all information:

```
dict= {'S': [['NP','VP']],
     'NP': [['DET', 'N']],
     'VP': [['V']], 'DET': [['a'], ['an']],
     'N': [['elephants'], ['elephant']],
     'V': [['talk'], ['smile]]}
```

I tried using this:

```
d = {}
elems  = filter(str.isalnum,l.replace('"',"").split("'"))
values = elems[1::2]
keys   = elems[0::2]
d.update(zip(keys,values))
```

and this:

```
s = l.split(",")
            
dictionary = {}

for i in s:
    dictionary[i.split(":")[0].strip('\'').replace("\"", "")] = i.split(":")[1].strip('"\'')
            
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Where did you get that list? Is it at all possible to generate something *meant* to be consumed by another process, like JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `re`:

```
import re, collections
l=["'S':'NP''VP'", "'NP':'DET''N'", "'VP':'V'", "'DET':'a'", "'DET':'an'", "'N':'elephant'", "'N':'elephants'", "'V':'talk'", "'V':'smile'"]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
   d[(k:=re.findall('\w+', i))[0]].append(k[1:])

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'S': [['NP', 'VP']], 'NP': [['DET', 'N']], 'VP': [['V']], 'DET': [['a'], ['an']], 'N': [['elephant'], ['elephants']], 'V': [['talk'], ['smile']]}
```